# What's the best way to input and store a url input in a web page in MySQL php?

Tags: php, url

I'm struggling a bit figuring out the best way accept and store a url from a web page.

Here's my approach:

1. It should be urlencoded since it's sent over the net to the server.
2. Specify the page as utf-8 in the header.
3. Use my_real_escape_string for inserting to the db.
4. Use strip_slashes on the input.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Where it should be urlencoded? On the server? After it's already got sent over the net? What's the point in it?

why use strip_slashes on the input?

what's so particular in storing urls, making it's processing different from whatever  other data?

Comment: Maybe I'm just overthinking it. I saw an example site that strip_slashed everything. I guess it has something to do with escape characters being inserted by the browser.

Comment: `stripslashes` is *never* the correct tool to use.  If you are encountering data that has slashes unexpectedly, then chances are that your server has `magic_quotes` enabled and you should find a *competent* host ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, you just need to validate, escape and trim a urls.

Comment: Can you give an example of escaping it?

Comment: Depends on what extension you use. It could be mysql_real_escape_string() or prepared statements of PDO...

Answer (score 1):

Use PDO for the database. And just trim your url.